# Deadlock in WPF app when resizing a window containing a HostVisual+D3DImage

Tags: wpf, multithreading, deadlock

I wrote a WPF application that uses `D3DImage` to show renders produced in a separate thread. The `D3DImage` is refreshed in the UI thread by using `Dispatcher.Invoke` from the D3D thread.

The D3D thread is running its own dispatcher.

I wanted to use `HostVisual`, so I did the following :

- Create the `D3DImage` in the D3D thread and use it only from that thread,
- Create a `VisualHost` from the UI thread add to the window's visual tree,
- Create a `VisualTarget` from the D3D thread and link it to the `VisualHost`.

This works very well: the content of the `D3DImage` is correctly rendered in the main window without any interference in the UI dispatcher...

...until I try to resize the main window, and the app *deadlocks*.

The deadlock occurs between the UI dispatcher and the D3D dispatcher. When the main window gets resized, what I understand from the reference sources of PresentationCore/PresentationFramework is that a new MIL channel is created for the new window size and the whole visual tree gets notified of it. This is the top of the callstack on the UI thread:

```
Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl <-- locked here
HostVisual.EnsureHostedVisualConnected
HostVisual.RenderContent
```

The UI thread is waiting for the D3D thread to complete a job from `HostVisual`. On the D3D thread's side the dispatcher executes the job and gets locked on the following callstack:

```
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilCompositionEngine_EnterCompositionEngineLock <-- locked here
HostVisual.DoHandleDuplication
```

The problem is that the composition engine's lock is currently acquired by the UI thread because of the resize operation, so the D3D thread will never be able to acquire it.

Is this a bug in `HostVisual`/`VisualTarget` or did I miss something?

Comment: Can you post enough code so someone can reproduce it?

Comment: I am doing something similar, but with a charting library.  I found I needed to fix the height and width of my charts.  I wish I could get them to autosize with the rest of the app.  This post seems to imply that this is possible.  How did you do it and did you ever solve the deadlock?